# Как сделать redirect из другого потока используя JSF Primefaces?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

У меня есть некий JSF компонент, хранящий состояние страницы специализаций. На этой странице пользователь выбирает специализацию, а затем ждёт действия со стороны другого пользователя. Так вот, если реализовать это последовательно, юзер зависнет на странице специализаций в бесконечном цикле, который будет проверять, совершено ли действие другим пользователем. Я хочу вынести это действие в другой поток для того чтобы юзер мог продолжать заниматься своими делами на странице, а когда бесконечный цикл в другом потоке завершится происходил редирект.

Проблема в том, что `PrimeFacesContext` не шарится между потоками (`ThreadLocal`). И запуская цикл в другом потоке я не могу совершить редирект средствами JSF, поскольку контекст - `null`.

Я в отдельном потоке запускаю цикл для проверки. И когда `this.isAccepted()`, пытаюсь делать редирект.

```
        ThreadPoolHolder.addNewTask(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (this.isAccepted()) {
                        PrimeFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/serve");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                LOG.error("Ошибка в задаче thread pool");
            }
        });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выйти из этой ситуации? Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема заключается в том, что объект PrimeFacesContext недоступен в другом потоке из-за использования ThreadLocal. Вместо использования отдельного потока для проверки состояния, вы можете использовать AJAX-запросы, чтобы проверять состояние на сервере и обновлять страницу клиента, когда состояние изменится.

Например, вы можете создать метод в управляемом бине, который проверяет состояние и возвращает результат в формате JSON. Затем вы можете использовать библиотеку JavaScript, например jQuery, чтобы отправлять AJAX-запросы на сервер с определенным интервалом и обновлять страницу, если состояние изменилось.

Примерный код на стороне сервера:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SpecializationBean implements Serializable {

    private boolean accepted = false;

    public void checkAccepted() {
        // проверка состояния и установка флага accepted
    }

    public boolean isAccepted() {
        return accepted;
    }

    public String getAcceptedAsJson() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("accepted", accepted);
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
}
```

Примерный код на стороне клиента с использованием jQuery:

```
function checkAccepted() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/checkAccepted",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.accepted) {
                window.location.href = "/serve";
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkAccepted, 1000); // повторить через 1 секунду
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error);
            setTimeout(checkAccepted, 1000); // повторить через 1 секунду
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkAccepted(); // начать проверку при загрузке страницы
});
```

Здесь функция checkAccepted отправляет AJAX-запрос на сервер по адресу /checkAccepted и ожидает ответ в формате JSON. Если ответ указывает на принятие, то происходит перенаправление на страницу /serve. В противном случае функция вызывает саму себя через 1 секунду, чтобы повторить проверку через определенный интервал времени. Функция checkAccepted вызывается при загрузке страницы с помощью события ready объекта jQuery.